OpenLayers 5 does not send WMTS GetTile request because of incorrect ScaleDenominator / resolutions?
I have a WMTS layer (it is a worldmap tiff file in CRS EPSG:4326) with grid size = 2048 * 1024 pixels, geo extent (Lon-Lat) = [-180, -90, 180, 90], geo resolution = 0.17578125 degree.
On the server, this WMTS layer has scale denominator as 69885282.88225446428571428571428571428571428571428571428572 (so 1 pixel is equivalent to that value in meters).
<TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>test_wmts_worldmap</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>69885282.88225446428571428571428571428571428571428571428572</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>90 -180</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>8</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>4</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>

Then, in OpenLayers 5 client, if I specify resolution = 0.17578125 then it works, the WMTS layer showed on OpenLayers.
tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
     
      resolutions: [
        0.17578125 // this value works
      ],
      matrixIds: [
        'test_wmts_worldmap',
      ],
      tileSize: [256, 256], // Tile dimensions
      extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90], // Full extent of EPSG:4326
    }),

However, if I changed to either (scale denominator = 69885282.88225446428571428571428571428571428571428571428572):

resolutions:  [ scale denominator ]
or resolutions:  [ scale denominator * 0.00028 ]

then OpenLayers does not send any WTMS GetTile request to server.
Does it mean the value of ScaleDenominator in meters calculated in WMTS server is incorrect for the TileMatrix with CRS EPSG:4326?
How can I get the resolution 0.17578125 from WMTS GetCapabilities for OpenLayers programmatically because I don't know beforehand the other layer's resolution to put manually in JavaScript code?

scale denominator * 0.00028 must be divided by the meters per unit
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/source/WMTS.js#L480
which for degree is based on radius on the earth
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/proj/Units.js#L48

The result should be the same as the tile size in degrees divided by size in pixels, 180 / 256, 90 / 256, 45 / 256, etc.

The answer is from Mike's reply here
OpenLayers 5 does not send WMTS GetTile request because of incorrect ScaleDenominator / resolutions?
So I will need to set:
 resolutions: [
        (69885282.88225446428571428571428571428571428571428571428572 * 0.00028) / 111138.50322222224
      ],


with
ScaleDenomiator = 69885282.88225446428571428571428571428571428571428571428572

and
metersPerDegree = 111138.50322222224

from the line https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/proj/Units.js#L48 which Miked showed
